# Fail to install older version of stringi using renv

Tags: r, installation, stringi, renv

I've been trying to install an older version of stringi using renv and am getting the following error. I've had a few earlier errors using restore, but a few restarts have been able to move things through. I tried removing and reinstalling stringi, but still end up with the same error when trying to load the appropriate version.

```
Installing stringi [1.4.3] ...
    FAILED
Error installing package 'stringi':
===================================

* installing *source* package 'stringi' ...
** package 'stringi' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0    -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c stri_ICU_settings.cpp -o stri_ICU_settings.o
g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0    -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c stri_TODO_justify.cpp -o stri_TODO_justify.o
g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0    -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c stri_TODO_splitpos.cpp -o stri_TODO_splitpos.o
g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0    -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c stri_TODO_uchar.cpp -o stri_TODO_uchar.o
g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0    -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c stri_brkiter.cpp -o stri_brkiter.o
stri_brkiter.cpp: In member function 'void StriBrkIterOptions::setType(SEXP, const char*)':
stri_brkiter.cpp:60:8: error: 'isNull' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'Rf_isNull'?
   60 |    if (isNull(opts_brkiter)) {
      |        ^~~~~~
      |        Rf_isNull
stri_brkiter.cpp: In member function 'void StriBrkIterOptions::setLocale(SEXP)':
stri_brkiter.cpp:130:8: error: 'isNull' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'Rf_isNull'?
  130 |    if (isNull(opts_brkiter)) {
      |        ^~~~~~
      |        Rf_isNull
stri_brkiter.cpp: In member function 'void StriBrkIterOptions::setSkipRuleStatus(SEXP)':
stri_brkiter.cpp:171:8: error: 'isNull' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'Rf_isNull'?
  171 |    if (isNull(opts_brkiter)) {
      |        ^~~~~~
      |        Rf_isNull
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/etc/x64/Makeconf:259: stri_brkiter.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'stringi'
* removing 'D:/Projects/project1/renv/staging/1/stringi'
Error: install of package 'stringi' failed [error code 1]
```

When I try to load the version directly using devtools it conflicts with renv

```
require(devtools)
install_version("stringi", version = "1.4.3", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

```
require(devtools)
Loading required package: devtools
Loading required package: usethis
Warning messages:
1: package ‘devtools’ was built under R version 4.2.2 
2: package ‘usethis’ was built under R version 4.2.2 
> install_version("stringi", version = "1.4.3", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
Downloading package from url: http://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/stringi/stringi_1.4.3.tar.gz
Installing package into ‘D:/Projects/project1/renv/library/R-4.2/x86_64-w64-mingw32’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
ℹ Using R 4.2.0 (lockfile was generated with R 4.0.3)
* installing *source* package 'stringi' ...
** package 'stringi' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
ERROR: cannot remove earlier installation, is it in use?
* removing 'D:/Projects/project1/renv/library/R-4.2/x86_64-w64-mingw32/stringi'
* restoring previous 'D:/Projects/project1/renv/library/R-4.2/x86_64-w64-mingw32/stringi'
Warning in file.copy(lp, dirname(pkgdir), recursive = TRUE, copy.date = TRUE) :
  problem copying D:\Projects\project1\renv\library\R-4.2\x86_64-w64-mingw32\00LOCK-stringi\stringi\libs\icudt69l.dat to D:\Projects\project1\renv\library\R-4.2\x86_64-w64-mingw32\stringi\libs\icudt69l.dat: Invalid argument
Warning in file.copy(lp, dirname(pkgdir), recursive = TRUE, copy.date = TRUE) :
  problem copying D:\Projects\project1\renv\library\R-4.2\x86_64-w64-mingw32\00LOCK-stringi\stringi\libs\x64\stringi.dll to D:\Projects\project1\renv\library\R-4.2\x86_64-w64-mingw32\stringi\libs\x64\stringi.dll: Permission denied
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpK41CGy/remotesce6857a77e39/stringi’ had non-zero exit status
>
```

Comment: Maybe your C++ is outdated. Please state OS/platform you're running.

Answer (score 0):

The OS/platform by jay.sf made me check over my setup and I realized that I was working with different versions of R. I installed the earlier version, called renv::restore() and the packages successfully installed.